# Get Timestamp from Database

Tags: php, module, joomla-3.4, mysql

I have data stored in a db table, with an auto timestamp. In a module I want to then display a result based on the latest timestamp.

It's not working and I'm getting an error

```
Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string
```

The query I've written is:

```
//Get Latest Update TimeStamp
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT MAX( timestamp )  
          FROM #__service_status ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";
$db->setQuery( $query);
$timestamp = strtotime($db);
```

Then I'm trying to echo it with:

```
<?php echo date("m-d-Y", $timestamp);?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add this in your code, after $db->setQuery( $query);

```
$db->setQuery( $query);
$var1= $db->loadResult();
$timestamp = strtotime($var1);
```

Hope this help

Comment: @RustyJoomla - Just thought I'd mention that it was because you were pushing the whole Joomla Database object to `strtotime` rather than the result of the database query ;)

Comment: If `loadResult()` will return `null` you will have a warning also. I advice to check the result before use it further, like `if (!empty($var1)) do something`.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL already provides the appropriate tools to reformat your timestamp value, so I strongly recommend that you wrap [DATE_FORMAT()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php) around your `MAX()` call.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MAX(timestamp), '%m-%d-%Y') AS `formatted` FROM `service_status`
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b415f1/1)

`MAX()` provides a more succinct query versus `ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1` which will also provide the desired output.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%m-%d-%Y') AS formatted FROM `service_status` ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

The take-away lessions are:

1. You don't need the redundant logic of `MAX()` and `ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1`.
2. You can spare a couple of php date function calls (namely: `strtotime()` & `date()`) by reformatting in your query.

The final baked product can look like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
try {
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
                ->select("DATE_FORMAT(MAX(timestamp), '%m-%d-%Y')")
                ->from("#__service_status");
    // echo $query->dump();  // uncomment if you want to see what is generated
    $db->setQuery($query);
    if (!$result = $db->loadResult()) {  // declare $result then check for a "falsey" value
        echo "No Rows Found";
    } else {
        echo "Last update was $result";
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Syntax Error"; // , $e->getMessage();  // <- don't show these details publicly
}
```

*since there is only a single value returned, I have removed the column alias that I first mentioned in my raw SQL query -- `loadResult()` doesn't care what the field is called.

*`timestamp` is a mysql KEYWORD but it is not a RESERVED KEYWORD so it doesn't *need* to be wrapped in backticks.